# Can a spell that targets a creature be cast on an area where the caster believes there is an invisible creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility, targeting

A Cleric wants to use Sacred Flame in an area where he thinks there is an invisible enemy.

His logic is something like this: Sacred Flame is something similar to fire from heaven, so I can "command" it to descend on an area where I think there is an invisible enemy.

Seems to make sense to me, so I choose to allow this. However, it seems ridiculous to allow Charm Person, Hold Person, etc. to follow this same house rule. **Should I allow those spells to be cast like that?**

Comment: Can you differentiate if you're looking at Sacred Flame specifically or spells in general?

Comment: @NautArch yes, the the bolded parts. The general spells that ask for target creature, but the caster want to cast in a specific place/area.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### No, you must see your target.

The text of Sacred Flame states (emphasis added),

> Flame-like radiance descends on a creature that **you can see** within range.

Likewise, stuff like Hold Person, Magic Missile, and Charm Person have similar wording:

> You attempt to charm a humanoid you can see within range.

The wording is clear that a creature must be targeted, so you cannot target a point in space. There are other spells that do allow you to target a point in space, though, like Fireball.

What about cases where the character believes that they see something that isn't actually there? Absent guidance from the rules, I'd rule that only sincere belief is necessary. Otherwise, you run into weird situations. For example, a character in a dungeon could cast sacred flame on everything they see, because it would only have an effect if a hidden creature were targeted.

### Other spells don't have this requirement

There are a few spells that don't have the "you can see" clause in them, like Eldritch Blast or Fire Bolt:

> You hurl a mote of fire at a creature or object within range

It's a little ambiguous how one should deal with that wording, but as a DM I would allow a character to target a creature that they believe, in good faith, exists and is invisible using these spells. You'll have to look at the specific wording of each spell.

It's worth noting that all spells require line of effect, so one can't abuse this wording to shoot around corners (PHB 204):

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can’t be behind total cover.

Comment: Although an area effect or something that only requires the target hear you would still work.

Comment: It's important to note that while both of these spells require a target that you can see, there are many that merely require a target in range. Those can be cast on an invisible creature.

Comment: What if your PC *thinks* she can see an enemy? If your PC *believes* she sees something that should count, right?

Comment: What about Acid Splash? "Choose one creature within range, or choose two creatures within range that are within 5 feet of each other.” this seems like an incomplete and possibly deceptive answer because it implies that all spells require sight which isn't true. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Xanathar's guide has specific rules for handling invalid targets, including when a character thinks they see something that isn't there.  Sincere belief or not, there is no effect, and you lose the spell slot - just as if the target made it's save.

Answer (score 7):

## Depends on the spell

*Sacred flame*, *hold person*, and *charm person* and others like it do require sight. *Sacred flame* for example says:

> Flame-like radiance descends on a creature that **you can see** within range.

**So *sacred flame* and any others that require sight to target cannot be used to target invisible creatures.**

However, a spell like *acid splash* does not:

> Choose one creature within range, or choose two creatures within range that are within 5 feet of each other.

Since this spell does not say anything about requiring sight thus does not require it.

**Spells that do not require sight to target a creature can be used to target invisible creatures.**

Note also that even if you are able to target an invisible creature you must still choose one specific square where you believe the enemy is (which may or may not be where it actually is).